# The Analytics for Hadoop service on Bluemix does not launch in a Firefox browser

Tags: hadoop, ibm-cloud, analytics-for-hadoop, analytics-for-apache-hdp

When I use Mozilla Firefox V40.0.2 to launch the service, I get the following error message:

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to bi-hadoop-
prod-2480.services.dal.bluemix.net:9443. SSL received a weak ephemeral
Diffie-Hellman key in Server Key Exchange handshake message. (Error code:
ssl_error_weak_server_ephemeral_dh_key) The page you are trying to view
cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be
verified. Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

The following URL shows in the address bar of Firefox: 
https://bi-hadoop-prod-2480.services.dal.bluemix.net:9443/SSOAuth/checkAccess.jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the service is probably using an obsolete encryption cipher and the cipher is vulnerable to the Logjam exploit. To resolve this issue, disable the old ciphers in Firefox and attempt to force the site to use another cipher. Complete these steps:

1. Open a new tab in Firefox and enter `about:config` in the address bar.
2. Acknowledge the “this might void your warranty!” warning and click **I’ll be careful, I promise!**
3. Type `dhe` in the Search box and click **Enter**.
4. Double-click the **security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_aes_128_sha** preference name, which switches the value from true to false.
5. Double-click the **security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_aes_256_sha** preference name, which switches its value from true to false.